# css dropdown menu items on one line and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, sass

Plase see Codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEAKo

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product group 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product group 2 with long name</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product 2 with long name</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery 2 with long name</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Subgallery 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subgallery 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subgallery 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subgallery 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

SASS (+Compass)

```
*, *:before, *:after
  box-sizing: border-box

.container
  max-width: 1140px
  margin: 0 auto
  background-color: lightblue
  border: 1px black solid  
  &:after
    clear: both
    display: table
    content: ' '
    height: 0
nav
  height: 86px
  background-color: yellow
  float: right
  a
    text-decoration: none
    color: blue
    &:visited
      color: blue
  li
    display: inline-block    
    position: relative
    &:hover
      > ul
        visibility: visible
  > ul 
    > li:hover
      background-color: #ddd
      & > a
        border-bottom: 3px darkred solid
    > li > a
      padding: 0 15px
      display: table-cell
      vertical-align: middle
      height: 86px
      border-bottom: 3px transparent solid
    ul
      position: absolute
      visibility: hidden
      background-color: #eee
      li
        border-bottom: 2px #bbb solid
        > a
          display: block
          padding: 10px 15px
          border-left: 3px transparent solid
        &:hover
          background-color: #ddd
        &:hover > a
          border-left: 3px darkred solid
      ul
        left: 100%
        top: 0
```

**Questions**

- How to deal with long names in menu items? I'd like that these menus was placed on one line.
- If I resize browser window - small horizontal scroll appears. For what reason? How to get rid?

[image: Scrollbar]

Comment: Like [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kbole)? Using `white-space: nowrap; display: block;` on `nav > ul ul li`

Comment: Thanks. It solves first problem. But horizontal scrollbar now is much longer :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of changing visibility, use `display:none` to hide `ul` and `display: block` to show. This will prevent the scroll bars caused by the dropdowns. *You will get the scroll bar when the dropdowns are active if the viewport is too small*
2. Set `white-space: nowrap` and `display: block` on the nested `li` to keep each dropdown menu item on its own line and prevent the text from wrapping

**Note:** If this is an English language site, or a language which is read left to right, you should keep the nav in the middle or on the left. This gives you maximum screen real estate for your dropdowns to expand over. Placing it on the right with multiple layers of dropdowns will cause usability problems (such as needing to scroll to see the dropdowns).

Having a menu like this on the right will only work for a language read right to left with the dropdowns cascading in the same direction.

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qlzeH)

SASS

```
*, *:before, *:after
  box-sizing: border-box

.container
  max-width: 1140px
  margin: 0 auto
  background-color: lightblue
  border: 1px black solid  
  &:after
    clear: both
    display: table
    content: ' '
    height: 0

nav
  height: 86px
  background-color: yellow
  float: right
  a
    text-decoration: none
    color: blue
    &:visited
      color: blue


  li
    display: inline-block    
    position: relative
    &:hover
      > ul
        display: block

  > ul 
    > li:hover
      background-color: #ddd
      & > a
        border-bottom: 3px darkred solid

    > li > a
      padding: 0 15px
      display: table-cell
      vertical-align: middle
      height: 86px
      border-bottom: 3px transparent solid

    ul
      position: absolute
      display: none
      background-color: #eee

      li
        border-bottom: 2px #bbb solid
        white-space: nowrap
        display: block

        > a
          display: block
          padding: 10px 15px
          border-left: 3px transparent solid
        &:hover
          background-color: #ddd

        &:hover > a
          border-left: 3px darkred solid

      ul
        top: 0
        left: 100%
```